# How to use a Multi-Select String field in a BQL Where

Tags: acumatica

I have a field in the unbound filter DAC for a custom processing screen that is a multi-select dropdown field.  It has the PXStringList attribute defined like this:

```
    #region POStatus
    [PXString]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "PO Status")]
    [PXStringList(new string[] { "N", "B" }, new string[] { "Open", "Pending Approval" }, MultiSelect =true)]
    public string POStatus { get; set; }
    public abstract class poStatus : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<poStatus> { }
    #endregion
```

How can I use this field in the Where clause of the BQL query for the main view?  So, in this case I'm trying to filter POOrder records by whatever statuses the user selects in the multi-select drop down.
I tried using the IsIn<> operator but, it doesn't build.

Do I have to resort to a view delegate in order to do this?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acumatica stores the values for the multi-select drop-downs in 1 field as comma-separated values. The first thing I would try would be to try using the Contains operation in opposite direction like below:

```
PXSelect<POOrder, Where<Current<FilterDAC.poStatus>, Contains<POOrder.status>>> FilteredPOList;
```

Comment: Man, I would have sworn that I tried that but, apparently not.  so simple.....  Thanks!

Comment: @MikeNIke have you checked if that code works or not? I haven't checked it that is why I recommended trying it and didn't say it was the way to do that

Comment: yeah, it works great.  I put it in with FBQL syntax but, it works like a champ.